# HTML and CSS, center divs in td

Tags: html, css, center, centering

I have a column in a table that contains and icon and a chunk of text. the icon is a div with a data url background. I need the cell to be a little bit bigger than the content and the content to be centered within the cell. I've been banging my head over this for a while now and can't get it to work.

CSS

```
body {
    width: 90%%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-family: &quot;Arial&quot;
}

table {
    /*width: 100%%;*/
        width: 100px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    font-size: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

td.bordered_centered {
    border: solid 1px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.icon {
    float: left;
    height: 20px;
    width: 35px;
    margin-right: 0.25em; /* 0.25em is roughly equal to one space character. */
}

.lastFour {
    float: left;
    width: 35px;
    padding-top: 2px;
}

.visa {
    background-image:           
url(data:image/png;base64,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);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

td,th {
    font-size: 95%;
}
```

HTML

```
<td class='bordered_centered cardNumber'  valign='center'>
  <div class='cardHolder'>
    <div class='icon visa'></div>
    <div class='lastFour'>9999</div>
  </div>
</td>
```

I can make it look right on some screens and some resolutions by using padding to center the text, but I can't get it looking good everywhere. It's to be viewed on phones and tablets so I can't just ignore some screen sizes.

I've also tried using an img with the data uri. That helps a little. Unfortunately it would make the page I'm trying to build monstrous so I'd like to avoid it if at all possible.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
vertical-align: center;
```

Is not correct; try:

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

Form more information see:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align

Comment: I should have mentioned, I already tried that. The "center" usage was from one of my many flailing attempts to make it work. I'll update the original post.